# Beacon PC or Android simulator

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, beacon, eddystone

I need some help about simulating Beacons, I was searching many small scripts for running a sumilator with no luck, I find no app of  a beacon simulator for android. Do you know one that is working? I need for test because I'm starting using the api for android. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) to transmit as a beacon on Android 5+ devices.  Here's an example:

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
    .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
    .setId2("1")
    .setId3("2")
    .setManufacturer(0x0118) // Radius Networks.  Change this for other beacon layouts
    .setTxPower(-59)
    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
    .build();

// Change the layout below for other beacon types
BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new     BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser); 
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Advertisement start failed with code: "+errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Advertisement start succeeded.");
        }
});
```

See more details here:  https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html

You can also use the off-the-shelf [Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) that is based on this library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know that what I'm gonna say is not a simulator for android devices, however when developing  an app for detection an receiving data from a beacon (for estimote beacons) in android devices and if u have a ipad handy, u can emulate beacons with estimote app. That solved my problem. Thanks for the other answer, I will try it too.